# disable buttons in Python and Tk

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

Learned group,

I am working on a gui with a row of Radiobuttons that must be disabled in mode "auto".

part of the script:

```
#  define Auto Manual Mode: 
def AM_procedure():
    global manual
    if vam.get()==1:
        am_mode.set("Auto")
        manual = False 
        for txt,val in space:
            space_button=Radiobutton(root, text = txt, value=val)
            space_button.configure(state = 'disabled')
    else:
        am_mode.set("Manual")
        manual = True
        for txt,val in space:
            space_button=Radiobutton(root, text = txt, value=val)
            space_button.configure(state='normal')
    print manual
    return;
```

snip...
The buttons:

```
for txt,val in space:
    space_button=Radiobutton(root, text = txt, font=fnt, indicatoron=0, width=8, variable=v, command=ShowChoice,value=val)
    space_button.grid(row=8, column=val-1)

for txt,val in AM:
    am_button=Radiobutton(root, text = txt, font=fnt, indicatoron=0, width=8, variable=vam, command=AM_procedure, value=val)
    am_button.grid(row=9, column=val+1)
```

Space contains 5 tuples, AM two. Pressing the auto button should, among other things, grey the first row out. I tried several things and I managed to grey only the last button out. But this script has no effect whatsoever.
Please advise.
thanks in advance,
Harke

Comment: I'm pretty sure I correctly formatted your code block but please feel free to edit your post and use the `{}` button or control-k to indent code blocks. If I didn't get it quite right :)

Comment: you create a set of RadioButtons and `grid()` them to put them on the screen but in AM_procedure you create a different set of buttons that are never placed on the GUI, I think you just need to keep a reference to the original widgets and configure them instead of creating new ones that never get shown.

Comment: I guess you are right. But how do I refer to the five buttons in stead of generating new ones? Sorry, yes I am in a learning phase....

Comment: Don't expect the "learning phase" to end, it certainly hasn't for me yet, I think it would be as simple as `radiobuttons = [] ... radiobuttons.append(space_button) ... for b in radiobuttons: b.grid(...)` but I'm not completely sure the best way to implement it into your program.

Comment: Thank you, Tadhg. I tried to understand but your proposal is not so clear to me. Can you be a bit more specific, please? In the meantime I constructed LabelFrames around the two sets of radiobuttons, looks nice. Unfortunately the state option does not apply to the LabelFrame, and as such not to its children, unfortunately. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with creating widgets like this:

```
for i in range(10):
    button=Button(root, text = i)
    button.grid(column=i)
```

is that once the `for` loop finishes there is no easy way to access the buttons created, there is still a variable `button` that will point to the last created widget and you can use `root.winfo_children()` to get every child of the root and configure all of them:

```
for w in root.winfo_children():
    w.configure(state="disabled")
```

but if you run this on the root window it will disable pretty much everything in your program.

What you really need is a way to *keep* references to all the buttons you create:

```
space_buttons = [] #list of space buttons

...

for txt,val in space:
    space_button=Radiobutton(root, text = txt, font=fnt, indicatoron=0, width=8, variable=v, command=ShowChoice,value=val)
    space_button.grid(row=8, column=val-1)
    #add it to the list of space buttons
    space_buttons.append(space_button)
```

then when ever you want to configure them you can use:

```
for button in space_buttons:
    button.configure(state="disabled")
```

The only potential problem is if the `space` list changes at some point in your program, in which case you would want a function to recreate the buttons:

```
def create_space_buttons():
    while space_buttons: #same as while len(space_buttons)>0:
        space_buttons.pop().destroy() #remove existing buttons

    for txt,val in space:
        space_button=Radiobutton(root, text = txt, font=fnt, indicatoron=0, width=8, variable=v, command=ShowChoice,value=val)
        space_button.grid(row=8, column=val-1)
        #add it to the list of space buttons
        space_buttons.append(space_button)
```

And possibly a similar function for `am_buttons`.

Comment: That's it!!!!! Thank you very much for the clear description of the solution and your time to help me out. Thanks a lot again! IOU